# How can I scan a column and show results based on occurrences of a certain item?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, countif, google-sheets-query, google-query-language

How can I scan a column within Google Sheets and show occurrence count?

Example:

- abc.com
- gb.com
- rt.com
- exe.com
- domain.com
- abc.com
- exe.com
- exe.com

Then on another tab within the same Google Sheet, I have it list.

```
- rt.com - 1
- exe.com - 3
- and so on.
```

I have tried writing the formula based on scripts I found online, but I have been unsuccessful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
=QUERY(A2:A, "select A,count(A) where A is not null group by A label count(A)''", 0)
```

[image: 0]

Comment: That's it. I modified it to work across pages


=QUERY('TABNAMEHERE'!C2:C, "select C,count(C) where C is not null group by C label count(C)''", 0)

Comment: How can I make it work across multiple pages?

=QUERY(2017!C2:C;2018!C2:C;2019!C2:C; "select C,count(C) where C is not null group by C label count(C)''", 0)

and if possible a-z them. alphabetize them

Comment: With that, I get "Formula Phase Error". there are matching values across the pages. I don't know why its throwing the error. thanks

Comment: I get #Value : Unable to parse query string for function QUERY parameter 2: NO_Column: C

but there is a c on each page and its the same content, urls...

Comment: like this: `=QUERY({2017!C2:C;2018!C2:C;2019!C2:C}, "select Col1,count(Col1) where Col1 is not null group by Col1 label count(Col1)''", 0)`

Comment: You got it.

This one works.
=QUERY({2017!C2:C;2018!C2:C;2019!C2:C}, "select Col1,count(Col1) where Col1 is not null group by Col1 label count(Col1)''", 0)

You are awesome, thank you so much